# Kivy Bug? The Enabled/Disabled property of a button doesn't seem to update, it only cares if the field exists and isn't equal to 0

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I'm working on an alarm clock program but ran into what seems to be a bug in the Kivy code. There are some extra variables listed, as I've been troubleshooting, but what appears to happen is if the "enabled" property exists for my button, and it has a value not 0, then the button starts and stays enabled. If it contains the "disabled" property instead, then the reverse is true. If it contains both, then it runs with disabled.

Attached is a picture of my troubleshooting, showing that the values are changing, but the widget doesn't update with it. The Hour10_up button is still clickable while it is not visible.

From main.py

```
class DigitalClock(FloatLayout):
    display_time = StringProperty("00 : 00")
    alarm_time = StringProperty("00 : 00")
    clock_view = StringProperty("1")
    settings_view = StringProperty("0")
    clock_disable = StringProperty("0")
    clock_enabled = StringProperty("1")
    settings_disabled = StringProperty("0")
    settings_enabled = StringProperty("0")

    def click_settings(self, *args):
        if args[1] == 'down':
            self.settings_view = "1"
            self.settings_disabled = "0"
            self.settings_enabled = "1"
            self.clock_enabled = "0"
            self.clock_disable = '1'
            self.clock_view = "0"
            print("clock disabled: " + self.clock_disable)
            print("settings  disabled: " + self.settings_disabled)
```

From digitalclock.kv

```
ToggleButton:
    id: 'button_settings'
    text: "Settings"
    font_size: 10
    size_hint: .1, .1
    pos_hint: {'x': 0, 'y': .9}
    on_state: root.click_settings(*args)

Button:
    id: 'hour10_up'
    opacity: self.parent.settings_view
    enabled: self.parent.settings_enabled
    text: "+"
    font_size: 10
    size_hint: .08, .1
    pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .6}
    on_release:
        root.hour10_up()
```

Troubleshooting pic

[image]

Comment: I just found "rebind" under [link]https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty and looks like it may do this by design for some reason, yet the Opacity property updates as I intend with the code.

Comment: I think the property you want is `disabled` rather than `enabled`.

Comment: I addressed this above. If "disabled" is used then the button starts as disabled when the program runs and remains disabled when the attached variable changes to "0" (not disabled). The 3 grayed out buttons in my image are an example of this. Those four buttons are: hour10_up, hour1_up, minute10_up, and minute1_up. The first of the grayed out buttons is hour1_up, also shown in the .kv file with the disabled property.